# $_GET and isset() url response Json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have use a lot of answers here to solve almost everything, but i can't figure out how to accomplish this;
I use PHP to get data from my MySQL, and encode to json with url request, so wen I go to miweb. com /_js/ajax/load_content.php?f=1
I get a perfect response from my databesa and echo to json encode, 1 means user with id number 1
my response looks like this:

```
[{"i":"1","n":"Azul","p":"_imgs\/site\/iconos\/0-100\/22\/activo\/ico_00022_138.jpg"}]
```

and if i go to miweb. com/_js/ajax/load_content.php?f=2   i will get

```
[{"i":"2","n":"Lety","p":"_imgs\/site\/iconos\/0-100\/87\/activo\/ico_00087_138.jpg"}]
```

what i need to accomplish is to go to ?f=1,2

miweb.com /_js/ajax/load_content.php?f=1,2  and get the response in same json like this

```
  [{"i":"1","n":"Azul","p":"_imgs\/site\/iconos\/0-100\/22\/activo\/ico_00022_138.jpg"},
  {"i":"2","n":"Lety","p":"_imgs\/site\/iconos\/0-100\/87\/activo\/ico_00087_138.jpg"}]
```

this is my php scrip:

```
    require  '../../system/config.php';
if( isset($_GET['h']) ) {
    get_ficha($_GET['h']);

} else {
    die("Solicitud no válida.");
}
function get_ficha( $id) {
    // CONECCION DATABASE//
    $database = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);
    if($database->connect_errno) {
        die("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos");
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($database, "utf8");
    //Sanitize ipnut y preparar query
    if( is_array($id) ) {
        $id = array_map('intval', $id);
        $promo = "WHERE `ID` IN (" . implode( ',', $id ) . ")";
    } else {
        $id = intval($id);
        $promo = "WHERE `ID` = " . $id;
    }
    if ( $result = $database->query( "SELECT * FROM (ficha)" . $promo) ) {
        if( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
                     $promo  = array();
                     while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                     { 
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $nombre=$row['nombre'];
                        $icono=$row['ico_138'];
                        $promo[] = array(
                            'i'=> $id,
                            'n'=> $nombre,
                            'p'=> $icono
                        );
                    }
        } else {
            $promo = array(

                );  
        }
        $result->close();
    } else {
        $promo["success"] = false;
        $promo["data"] = array(
                    'message' => $database->error
                );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($promo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $database->close();
}
exit();
```

Comment: is this system supposed to segregate user `stuff` from one-another in a private manner or is it communal / do whatever you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explode the get variable

```
get_ficha(explode(',', $_GET['h']));
```

Then in your function

```
    if( is_array($id) && count($id) > 1) {
        $id = array_map('intval', $id);
        $promo = "WHERE `ID` IN (" . implode( ',', $id ) . ")";
    } else {
        $id = intval($id);
        $promo = "WHERE `ID` = " . $id;
    }
```

Comment: @DataNetwork no worries at all, i'm glad i could help